# How to run shell script during Docker run

Tags: docker

I got an existing Docker container. 
I need to run a shell script inside of it:

Now I need to access via shell and run commands manually:

```
nvidia-docker run --publish 127.0.0.1:8080:8888 -it gcr.io/project/container:latest bin/bash
```

and then

```
cd folder/demo/folder2
python demo.py -m "./data/mydata" -o ./lalala.engine -c ./data/dadada/
jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root
```

How can I start container and run commands without having to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own docker image (Dockerfile) by using the `nvidia-docker` as base image and then override the `entrypoint` with a custom script.

```
FROM nvidia-docker
COPY ./script.sh /scripts/script.sh
ENTRYPOINT /scripts/script.sh
```

and in script.sh do:

```
cd folder/demo/folder2
python demo.py -m "./data/mydata" -o ./lalala.engine -c ./data/dadada/
jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root

# Watever else you want
``
```